# grails 3.0.2 mysql connectivity

Tags: mysql, grails, java-8, grails-3.0

I have installed grails 3.0.2 and xampp server on my system. I want to connect to MySql of Xampp through grails. So made some changes in **application.yml** file located at grails-app/conf folder now it looks like

```
dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4MySQLConnection"//changed driver class
username: root                            //username 
password: 123456                          //password
```

//now in develoment environments i changed dbCreat->update and

//url-> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB
//i have not made any changes to test and production environments

environments:

```
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

I am new to grails so i don't know where to place mysql-connector.jar but i have added path of my mysql-connector.jar in .dependencies file located at myProject/build folder.

When i try to run my app it gives a lot of errors and in end it gives exception as

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4MySQLConnection
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(Poole
>   dConnection.java:246)
>           ... 83 more

i am not able to understand error.
If their is any step my step tutorial for mysql connection with grails 3.0.2 and jdk 1.8 please post link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually a mysql jar missing from classpath. as you are on tomcat, it usually is in the WEB-INF (sp?) folder

Comment: WEB-INF/lib folder, if on tomcat. I guess we need to know what servlet engine if there is one.

Comment: You should use 3.0.4 to ensure that this isn't something that was fixed in 3.0.3 or 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3.0 uses the Gradle build system for:

> build related tasks such as compilation, runnings tests and producing binary distrubutions of your project

So you can add your dependency in the `build.gradle` file, inside the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies ...
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
}
```

See the [Grails Gradle Build documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#gradleBuild) and [Gradle Dependency Management Basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) to learn more about this.